# Discord bot doesn't send welcome messages | JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am stuck on the welcoming feature of my discord bot.

It doesn't send any message.

Here is the code for the welcome.js file:

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
        
        const welcomechannel = '934868156399386676';
        const ruleschannel = '934877916041457774';

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`New member has arrived!`)
        .setDescription(`Welcome to the server <@${member.id}>! Enjoy your stay and make sure to check our rules ${member.guild.channels.cache.get(ruleschannel).ToString()}! :slight_smile:`)
        .setColor('#0ed42a')
        .setTimestamp()
        client.channels.cache.getwelcomechannel.send(embed)
    })
```

here is the code for the index.js file:

```
onst { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const config = require("./config.json");
const welcome = require("./welcome.js");

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Your bot is online!");


    welcome(client);
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: You need to include `GUILD_MEMBERS` in your client's intents as well as enable it in your developer portal to receive guild member events. The answer below also addresses your second problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is both in the index.js and the welcome.js

first of all your not including `GUILD_MEMBERS` as an intent in index.js.

Your second issue in the welcome.js. `getwelcomechannel` is not a valid property of [ChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=cache), so as @bedstorm said you can use the [get()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) function and pass in the channel id. Your code in welcome.js should look like this

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {

        const welcomechannel = '934868156399386676';
        const ruleschannel = '934877916041457774';

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`New member has arrived!`)
            .setDescription(`Welcome to the server <@${member.id}>! Enjoy your stay and make sure to check our rules <#${ruleschannel}>! :slight_smile:`)
            .setColor('#0ed42a')
            .setTimestamp()
        client.channels.cache.get(welcomechannel).send(embed);
    })
}
```

Then just add the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent to your client